# User Relationships - Full Profile2 Access

Tags: users

I am looking to create a dating site using Drupal which is similar to Tinder, where you swipe/mark your interest in another user and if that user swipes/marks an interest back, then contact information is shared.

### Match Making Process

1. Man can see a list of women
   (The above I should be able to do with search results/views)
2. Man likes woman and 'flags/marks' their interest
3. Woman is notified
4. Woman accepts or declines
   a. If accept - their contact information is shared with each other
   b. If declined - notification is sent to man

(this process is reversed for women seeking men)

### Profile

Name - Public
Age - Public
Telephone number - Private until shed with certain user
Email address - Private until shed with certain user

What I am wondering is how to upon 4.a. (Accept) to share the Private Contact information of the profiles with the other parties? SOLVED - User Relationships & Profile2

### EDIT

I have discovered the User Relationships module which does 90% of what is required. However, how would I allow friends access to each others Profile2 full profiles?

Comment: I haven't used User Relationships in a very long time (maybe D6). I had built a small Facebook like clone for a niche market of folks. If I recall, the way I had done it was I set up some menu items with a custom page callback and custom access hook that checked the current user against the user they were accessing (uid in url) and if they had a relationship record. If they did they could access the page, if not it would say something like "you are not friends with this person" or something of that nature and show nothing. I think UR even has a helper function that checks relationship.

Comment: That is to say, if you really want to do it up, create your own menu routes and build the experience. It might take a little longer, but you will get complete control.

Comment: Ideally it would be great if UR and P2 worked with each other by IF relationship = [x] then show Profile Type [y]. So that different profile types could be shown depending on the type of relationship the users had with each other.